# Offered a team lead role at work, accepted the role verbally. Received contract late and have not signed it yet

Tags: career-development

I have had an interview at work for a team lead role.  Was successful and was offered the role which I accepted verbally.  Received the contract very late and still have not yet signed it.  During such time I have been partially learning and training within this role moved into the office, got the car etc but still have not signed as their are some discrepancies within the contract which I keep addressing.  The concerns I have raised seem to be falling upon deaf ears and disregarded.

My question is:  What sort of blow back should I expect when I don't sign and tell them I am not going to take this role?

Comment: Why are you not taking the role anymore? Is it because of your experience over the contract? Because of what you've seen while partially doing it? Personal reasons? Just changed your mind?

Comment: There are heaps of factors that will determine how much blow back there is. It's impossible to say. There will almost certainly be blow back if people have invested effort to make this happen.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if there is a verbal agreement and if you *act* like you have accepted the new role: riding your car, do the learning, receive the training, etc. then you have accepted your new role.

The people in your company have the right to believe they have a new team lead. When withdrawing they will be disappointed. It depends on how resentful the people at your company are for how big the blow back will be. I would expect at least some blow backs on my personal account, maybe some legal issues with repaying costs (if that is in the contract) and most likely they will not offer you such a position anymore. This is what I have is seen in companies I worked before where people feel betrayed and became resentful.